# thickbox and jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, thickbox, uidatepicker

i am using thickbox with jquery ui datepicker in one of my asp.net page, the datepicker is not visible , i changed the z index of the datepicker also but nothing is coming out, what should i do

Comment: Does the datepicker work on its own?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: @kopanski its working in stand alone, @marco none even with fire bug
@ Natrium sorry boss it is just a hyper link with another page so i assumed that is not necessary. more over a lot of search is on this topic in google

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the date picker (calling the plugin function) **AFTER** thickbox appears. Usually a delayed call on the link opening the thickbox will do, example:

```
$("#thickbox_link").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#datepickerdiv").datepicker();
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: will try and get back, meanwhile i found another thing lightwindow which is doing the same job but it is not hurting the ui datepicker. so i am started to using that.